# Converting signed int to unsigned short with negative values being set to zero in C

Tags: c, type-conversion, integer, unsigned-integer, ansi-c

I would like to know if there is an efficient way of converting a signed integer to an unsigned short where negative integer values are simply set to 0 in the unsigned short (in C ANSI). I know that this can be done with a simple if statement like the following:

```
int val1;
unsigned short val2;

val1=-5; 
if(val1<0){
   val2=0;
}else{
   val2=(unsigned short) val1;
}
```

This conversion occurs very often in my program and the case `val1` is negative is very rare, so it seems like overkill to have this if statement occur every single time.

Is there a more efficient way of making this conversion?

Comment: If it's an uncommon case the branch predictor might be good enough (depending on your architecture, obviously).

Comment: I suggest you to write the more occuring condition in `if` and then use `else` for less occuring cond.

Comment: Also try `val2 = val1 * (val1 > 0);` and do your measuring.

Comment: You could make an `inline` function (like `inline si2us(int si, unsigned short *us)`) to handle the conversion. Note that `inline` is from C99 and may not be implemented by the Microsoft Visual Studio C compiler.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think it's called `__inline` in MSVC's C compiler. But in any case, it's not ANSI C.

Comment: @pmg If that were an answer, I'd upvote it. I've successfully used that pattern to optimize numerical code.

Comment: This check is unavoidable, better use ternary operator ?: as 
val2 = val1<0 ? 0 : (unsigned short) val1;

Answer (score 3):

One thing that often works is using boolean results (`0` or `1`) directly in expressions.

Instead of your `if`/`else` construct try

```
val2 = val1 * (val1 > 0);
```

And don't forget to measure different codes with different compiler options if you're after the absolute best performance.

Comment: Wouldn't a multiplication take longer than a conditional statement? Or does that depend on the compiler?

Comment: This is a simple multiplication by `0` or `1`. The statement has no branching. It might work better than the `if`; it might not. **You need to measure.** Point is: the method is worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

I intend to run this embedded, so this might change, but running it in visual studio 2 million times didn't show significant differences in computation time on my CPU. But as I said, this might change when I embed it, so I will keep it in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are under gcc, you can use the built-in function to give the optimizer a clue about the likely result of an integer (or Boolean) expression.

```
#define likely(x)      __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)
#define unlikely(x)    __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)
```

In the following example, we are marking branch as likely true:

```
const char *home_dir ;

home_dir = getenv("HOME");
if (likely(home_dir))
    printf("home directory: %s\n", home_dir);
else
    perror("getenv");
```

Adatped to your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define likely(x)      __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)
#define unlikely(x)    __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)

int main(void)
{
    int val1;
    unsigned short val2;

    val1 = -5; 
    if (unlikely(val1 < 0)) {
        val2 = 0;
    } else {
        val2 = (unsigned short)val1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Another way using specified widths and bitwise operators:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    int32_t val1;
    uint16_t val2;

    val1 = -5; 
    val2 = (0xffff ^ (val1 >> 31)) & val1;
    printf("%u\n", val2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not using gcc, but I will take a look and see if my compiler has something similar to the __builtin_expect. I am using the IAR compiler for embedded systems.

Answer (score 1):

Here are several different ways to do it:

```
val2 = (unsigned short)val1 * (1+(val1>>(sizeof(val1)*8-1)));
val2 = (unsigned short)val1 * (1^((val1>>(sizeof(val1)*8-1))&1));
val2 = (unsigned short)val1 * (1^((unsigned)val1>>(sizeof(val1)*8-1)));
val2 = (unsigned short)val1 * (1-((unsigned)val1>>(sizeof(val1)*8-1)));
```

You can make it more generic by replacing the `8` with `CHAR_BIT` (defined in limits.h).

Please note that it is not necessarily more efficient than a simple `if/else` statement.